# Ideal Operational Amplifier excercise

Tags: power, operational-amplifier, amplifier

Having an ideal operational amplifier on the circuit below, i need to find the power at R3. Can you help me? Isn't it 0? I couldn't find anything similar on my books. [image]

Comment: The power is indeed zero if R3 is not connected to the output of the amplifier. (There's no dot, and it's bad practice to draw 4 way connecting intersections.)  However, if it is connected it is only zero when Vin is zero.  If this is homework what's your reasoning so far, and what have you tried in order to solve the problem?

Comment: I am sorry for the bad drawing, R3 is indeed connected to the output of the amplifier. This problem is from an exam that I failed and I am trying to understand it because even if I realise that it is probably simple, I am a total beginner.

Comment: Do you know how to find `Vo`?

Comment: Isn't it Vo = [(R1+R2)/R1]Vin ? I'm not sure, does R3 change things?

Comment: OK, you know Vout (No, R3 doesn't change Vout) therefore you know the voltage across R3.  What's the power dissipated in a resistor with Vout volts across it?

Comment: oh! So it's P3=Vo*I3 and the current is I3=Vo/R3 !!!(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this image for detailed analysis of the answer
[image]

Comment: Why is this an image instead of text/LaTeX?

Comment: @ Null. Somehow I could not figure out to type in equations directly, so I had to post the image instead. Any advice regarding using LaTeX directly will be helpful to me.

Answer (score -1):

power: P3 = Vo*I3 ,
voltage: Vo = [(R1+R2)/R1]*Vin ,
current: I3 = Vo/R3